# Lazy load json data from template engine (handlebars)

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, lazy-loading, template-engine

I am trying to lazy load content that I am getting from a json file using handlebars.js as a template engine.

**I want to lazy load each .projects-list div on scroll.**

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="projects-list">
    <script id="projects-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">​
        {{#each this}}
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
        <img class="lazy" src="{{image.small}}" height="130" alt="{{name}}"/>
        <img class="lazy" data-src="{{image.small}}" height="130" alt="{{name}}"/>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

// Get project data from json file.
$.getJSON("projects.json", function (data) {

    // Write the data into our global variable.
    projects = data;

    // Call a function to create HTML for all the products.
    generateAllProjectsHTML(projects);

});

// It fills up the projects list via a handlebars template.
function generateAllProjectsHTML(data) {

    var list = $('.projects-list');

    var theTemplateScript = $("#projects-template").html();

    //Compile the template​
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
    list.append(theTemplate(data));
}

$('.lazy').lazy({
    effect: "fadeIn",
    effectTime: 5000,
    threshold: 0
});

});
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Example Name 1",
    "image": {
      "small": "assets/images/example1.jpg",
      "large": "assets/images/example2.jpg"
    }
},
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Example Name 2",
    "image": {
      "small": "assets/images/example3.jpg",
      "large": "assets/images/example4.jpg"
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to use this plugin: http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/ but I am open to any suggestions.

***Thanks for taking the time to look, any help is greatly appreciated!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the order of your script and the timings. It would be a race-condition. You should initialize Lazy right after the template has been loaded. That should solve the behavior.

You can even compress your script. And remove the jQuery ready states in the script, it is not needed here.

So the result would look like this:

```
$.getJSON("projects.json", function(data) {
    var theTemplateScript = $("#projects-template").html();
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);

    $("#projects-list").append(theTemplate(data));

    $(".lazy").lazy({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        effectTime: 5000,
        threshold: 0
    });
});
```